# Why can't I call the method declared directly in the custom Application

Tags: android

It is a MVVM sample code from **florina-muntenescu**.

In his **DroidconApplication.java**, a getViewModel() method declared and called in the **MainActivity**.

Therefore I want to implement it into my project, I did the same thing declared in a custom Application, implemented the application into the **AndroidManifest.xml**, but couldn't find the getViewModel() in my **MainActivity**.

I searched for the answer, which is get the custom application first by

`Application app = (CustomApplication) getApplication();`

and call method by the app reference.

Then why not the same as the sample code?

what did I wrong?

[Sample source code in Github](https://github.com/florina-muntenescu/DroidconMVVM/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried with this

```
Application app = (CustomApplication) getApplication();
app.getViewModel();
```

`app.getViewModel()` won't work because `getViewModel()` actually exist in `CustomApplication` class. It will work at runtime as app is an instance of `CustomApplication` but at compile time there is no way Compiler will understand that `app` is actually instance of `CustomApplication`.

So use this :

```
CustomApplication app = (CustomApplication) getApplication();
app.getViewModel();
```

Comment: Could you look up the sample code? It didn't use any of these code above. It just called ViewModel viewModel = getViewModel(); directly in MainAcitivity.

Comment: Check `MainActivity` there is a method `getViewModel() ` did you used this mathod?

Comment: `and call method by the app reference.` what you mean with this line? I thought you have called `app.getViewModel();`